# CPU inference in libtorch causes OOM with repeated calls to forward

Tags: c++, windows, pytorch, libtorch

I have some libtorch code that is doing inference on the cpu using a model trained in pytorch that is then exported to torchscript. The code below is a simplified version of a method that is being repeatedly called.

```
void Backend::perform(std::vector<float *> in_buffer,
                      std::vector<float *> out_buffer) {
  c10::InferenceMode guard;

  at::Tensor tensor_out;
  at::Tensor tensor_in = torch::zeros({ 1, 16, 2 }); 
  std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs = { tensor_in };

  // calling forward on the model "decode," this is where 
  // the memory leak happens
  tensor_out = m_model.get_method("decode")(inputs).toTensor(); 
  
  auto out_ptr = tensor_out.contiguous().data_ptr<float>();

  for (int i(0); i < out_buffer.size(); i++) {
    memcpy(out_buffer[i], out_ptr + i * n_vec, n_vec * sizeof(float));
  }
}
```

m_model is the .ts file loaded via:

```
m_model = torch::jit::load(path);
m_model.eval();
```

Every call it seems that more of the torch graph is being allocated, and it isn’t being freed causing the program to eventually OOM and crash. Commenting out the forward call causes the the memory usage to stabilize.

My understanding is that InferenceMode guard should turn off autograd memory buildup which seems to be the normal cause of these issues.

I tried mimicking this in pytorch (by repeatedly calling forward from a loop), and there’s no memory issues which seems to point to this being a libtorch issue rather than an issue with the model itself.

My system:

OS: Windows 10/11

pytorch version: 1.11.0

libtorch version: 1.11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in the windows implementation of libtorch. Memory leaks can happen when calling forward on a separate thread from the main thread (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24237), and moving the forward call to the main thread fixed the issue.

Even though the issue is marked closed the bug is still present.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, with my forward method taking too much memory without releasing it. It's not exactly the same piece of code, yet you could try it. The most important thing seems to put the whole code into the scope of `torch::NoGradGuard`, in my case I also forced the input tensor to be in no grad with `set_requires_grad(false)`

Code :

```cpp
void main(...){
   torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;
   Mat x;
   ... // in my case x was a gray image
   at::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(x.data, {1, x.rows, x.cols, 1}, at::kByte);
   ... // permute tensor channels
   tensor_image.set_requires_grad(false);
   
   vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
   inputs.push_back(tensor_image);
   at::Tensor output;
   output = model.forward(inputs).toTensor();
   output = output.squeeze().detach();
   ...
}
```

Before in few seconds my disk space would be totally full, with those modifications the disk memory is now stable.

Comment: `c10::InferenceMode guard` turns off autograd, so it doesn't need to be explicitly called